# Check if event was scheduled - schedule event only once

Tags: wp-cron, cron

I have some programming error in my wordpress plugin. When its running, then it keeps registering cron job to the wordpress. I wrote the plugin as a class:

```
class Cleverstart_Woofio extends WC_Integration{
    public function __construct(){
       add_action('woofio_hourly', array( $this,'woofio_create_haystack'));
       wp_schedule_event(time(), 'hourly', 'woofio_hourly');
       //other stuff not related to the question
    } 

   public function woofio_create_haystack(){
     //do quite performance heavy stuff
   }

}

$cleverstart_woofio = new Cleverstart_Woofio();
```

My theory is, that the `new Cleverstart_Woofio();` call will always schedule new cron event, clugging my site. I need to check if the event was already scheduled and schedule it only once. However, I am clueless on how to achieve this.

Thanks for help

Answer (score 5):

Have you ever heard of [Rubber Ducking](https://rubberduckdebugging.com/)?

The [official documentation](https://developer.wordpress.org/plugins/cron/scheduling-wp-cron-events/) has an answer:

```
if ( ! wp_next_scheduled( 'woofio_hourly' ) ) {
    wp_schedule_event( time(), 'hourly', 'woofio_hourly' );
}
```

Comment: Please be aware that this check fails if the hook execution has arguments!